# Integrating by Parts in Evan's book

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

> How to perform Integrating by Parts here (Evan's PDE Book page 50-51)

You have to do $3$ times integration by parts to move the operator from $f$ to $\Phi$, but then you have to get $4$ terms. I think one needs also Fubini then below the first integral is OK after IBP, but for the other $2$ I have something like $\int_{\varepsilon}^{t}\partial_x \Phi_s fds$ and $-\int_{\varepsilon}^{t}\Phi_s \partial_xf ds$ (and Why are the images so big ?)

How to get from here,

[image]

to here

[image]

Comment: Break your initial integral into two integrals and the perform integration by parts for each of it. For the first integral involving $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ use integration by parts once (after changing the order of the integration). From this you'll obtain those two additional expressions with $f(x-y,t-\epsilon)$ and $f(x-y,0)$. For the second integral with $\Delta$ use integration by parts twice or Greens formula.

Comment: @Tomas thanks, but can you explain how to evaluate integrals like $-\int_{\epsilon}^{t}\phi(y,s)\partial f(x-y,t-s)\Big\lvert_{\mathbb R^n}ds+\int_{\epsilon}^{t}\partial_y \phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)\Big\lvert_{\mathbb R^n}ds$ it should give zero by the way. After IBP w.r.to $y$ you get these integrals

Comment: Notice that $\Phi$ approach zero at infinity (and in any direction), so that those integrals disappear.